# Git bash/mingw32 not showing whole stderr

Tags: mingw, stderr, neko

Given executable `Sea.exe` which throws an error to `stderr`, compare the two:

Windows `cmd.exe`:

```
D:\Dev\Sea\Export\windows\neko\debug\bin>Sea.exe
Called from thx.fp._Map.Map_Impl_::$statics line 1
Called from ApplicationMain::main line 143
Called from ApplicationMain::create line 26
Called from lime.app.Preloader::create line 58
Called from openfl.display.Preloader::start line 93
Called from NMEPreloader::onLoaded line 107
Called from openfl.events.EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent line 95
Called from openfl.display.DisplayObject::__dispatchEvent line 269
Called from openfl.events.EventDispatcher::__dispatchEvent line 237
Called from openfl.display.Preloader::display_onComplete line 129
Called from lime.app.Preloader::start line 242
Called from lime.app.Event_Void_Void::dispatch line 145
Called from ApplicationMain::init line 87
Called from ApplicationMain::start line 173
Called from Type::createInstance line 109
Called from DocumentClass::$init line 212
Called from DocumentClass::new line 239
Called from Main::new line 13
Uncaught exception - Invalid operation (+)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

And git bash/mingw64:

```
test@test-HP MINGW64 /d/Dev/Sea/Export/windows/neko/debug/bin (master)
$ ./Sea.exe
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

I checked if the exception is written to `stderr`, using this:

Windows `cmd.exe`:

```
D:\Dev\Sea\Export\windows\neko\debug\bin>Sea.exe 2> nul

D:\Dev\Sea\Export\windows\neko\debug\bin>
```

And checked [neko VM source code](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/neko/blob/d7e1293a712e5996b1fdd617fa370e8c420e841f/vm/main.c#L168-L175).

I'm not knowlegable enough to find the cause. Does the VM detect pseudo-linux environment and prints messages in some different stream?

Thank you.